# Unusual statement in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to read through a windows batch script and replicate its function in python. However, I have come across a statement I am not familiar with... Having little experience with batch myself.

```
set variable = %variable:~-2%
```

Can anyone explain to me what this means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take the last 2 characters from `variable` and assign the result to `variable`.

For example:

```
SET  A=12345
ECHO %A:~-2% 
REM  This will print out "45"
```

See the "Substrings" section [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntset.php#SubStr) for reference, and more examples.

Comment: Thanks very much. Especially for the link!